# Ctrl + . (Dot) keyboard combination crashes web-based applications

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, crash, shortcuts, visual-studio-code

So I was ccoding in VSCodium when I tried to use its "Quick Fix" feature, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + .</kbd>. However that caused VSCodium to crash. I thought that was a VSCodium problem, but when I performed the keyboard shortcut in Firefox it also crashed. Same thing with Discord. However other apps don't crash when I perform this keyboard shortcut.

System Info:

> Operating System: Kubuntu 23.10
> KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.8
> KDE Frameworks Version: 5.110.0
> Qt Version: 5.15.10
> Kernel Version: 6.5.0-14-generic (64-bit)
> Graphics Platform: X11
> Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-13400
> Memory: 15.4 GiB of RAM
> Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
> Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
> Product Name: B760M DS3H AX DDR4

I have no idea why does happens. I would love some help.

Comment: You can check keymaps in your system settings or try disabling any services that might intercept those shortcuts.

Comment: I already checked everywhere I could think of, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, this one is a weird one. For some reason, my system likes to corrupt itself every once in a while. Causing the system to be read-only and forcing me to run `sudo fsck`. This corrupts some packages, I can view what packages are corrupted with the `debsums` utility and this command: `sudo debsums -c | xargs -rd '\n' -- dpkg -S | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -u`, showed that the `fonts-noto-core fonts-noto-color-emoji` were corrupted. After reinstalling said packages, everything works fine. Weird...